# 32bit Qt application can't start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows, qt, dll

I have a problem with running my 32bit C++/Qt application without Qt Creator. While it starts I'm getting the following error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
```

This app starts correctly when I'm running its in Qt Creator. What should I do to open its by .exe file? I checked this app using `DUMPBIN /header`

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
    14C machine (x86)
    (...)
OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
    10B magic # (PE32)
```

I use Windows 7 64 bit but my application is 32 bit, so I checked .exe in Dependency Walker and I saw, that 3 modules in main dependency have 64bit icons. What is the reason and why program runs successfully when I use Qt Creator? I compile my app using`qmake.exe r -spec win32-g++` and `mingw32-make.exe`

[image: 64bit libs]

Comment: Does this happen with a *hello world* application? Can you share the source code of a minimal app that reproduces this problem?

Comment: No, simple applications like "Hello world" doesn't reproduce this problem. In my program I use some additional libraries (i.e libeay32), so I thought that this error is connected with them. I tried to find which module is response for it, I rebuilded several times my project and now... my app crashes (in Qt Creator) in release mode (but not in debug) returning code `0xc0000135`. I have .NET Framework installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [32-bit Qt application on win 7 x64 won't run, but runs fine from Qt Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099117/32-bit-qt-application-on-win-7-x64-wont-run-but-runs-fine-from-qt-creator)